# Execute SQL file which contains multiple stored procedures in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

How can I execute a SQL file which contains multiple stored procedures and a lot of SQL script in Node.js?

I have tried to execute the sql file using npm package execsql but it doesn't work. [Here is the link](http://npmjs.com/package/execsql) which I have tried.

1. Able to install
2. Did DB configuration
3. Getting this error while executing sql statement or sql file:

   ```
   Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'usernane'@'myipaddress' (using password: YES) –
   ```

Yet I am able to execute sql statements using npm package mysql with the same db configuration.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Vincent - I have tried to execute sql file using npm package execsql but it doesn't workout. Here is the below link which i have tried.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/execsql

1. Able to install
2. Did DB configuration
3. Getting error while executing sql statement or sql file and below is the error i am getting 
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'usernane'@'myipaddress' (using password: YES)

Comment: Where as, Able to execute sql statements using npm package mysql using same db configuration.

Comment: You should explain this in your question, that will make it more likely to be answered.

Comment: @Vincent - Edited my question. Thanks.